# How do I remove the dots from the login screen?

Tags: lightdm, unity-greeter

I can change the background image that Unity Greeter displays, but regardless of the image I choose, it's overlaid with a grid of dots. The dots look OK on the default background, but they look horrible on the background I want to use. How can I get rid of them?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**For 12.04 and 14.04**

Try the following commands in a terminal. It should work.

```
sudo xhost +SI:localuser:lightdm
sudo su lightdm -s /bin/bash
gsettings set com.canonical.unity-greeter draw-grid false
exit
```

References:

- http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=11840170&postcount=25
- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1958219

Comment: +1 for giving the correct answer for 12.04. I'd remove the second `exit` though, it assumes that you opened a terminal just for this sequence of statements and want to close it again.

Comment: For some reason this worked on one 12.04 machine but not on another.

Comment: @detly If it doesn't work in one machine, I am not exactly sure if my answer is wrong. Can you give us more info?

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally submitted that comment before I meant to. I found that the [Ubuntu Tweak Tool](https://launchpad.net/~tualatrix/+archive/ppa) has a toggle for it anyway, which worked for me.

Comment: @detly I am glad it eventually worked for you. Now that you are on 12.04, can you also check out the Zeitgeist question? *wink*

Comment: Haha yes, that was next on my list :)

Comment: Also works on 14.04

Comment: Also works on 16.04

Answer (score 13):

## This answer applies only to Ubuntu 11.04

Thanks to @Blitz and @Zoke for their answers. However, I've created a more complete solution. I've modified the package `unity-greeter` to remove the dots and I've packaged it in a PPA.

Anyone who wants to be rid of the dots can use [my PPA](https://launchpad.net/~scott.severance/+archive/lightdm). Here are instructions:

1. Add the PPA:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:scott.severance/lightdm
   ```
2. Run `sudo apt-get update`
3. Run `sudo apt-get upgrade`
4. The dots are now gone.

Comment: If you downvote, please explain why.

Comment: Presumably because forking unity-greeter is overkill, and relying on a PPA to maintain an important package (even if unity-greeter is mainly just configuration) is not ideal.  And there is a much simpler configuration-only solution.

Comment: @mmj: At the time this was posted, it was the only way. I filed a bug containing my patch which was accepted upstream. Now, upstream has changed the way they handle configuration. I fail tosee how my solution was o erkill

Answer (score 3):

It is hard coded in the sources. I have disabled it on my install by making a small change in the source of user-list.vala.

A quick step by step guide.

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
apt-get source unity-greeter
sudo apt-get build-dep unity-greeter
cd unity-greeter-0.1.1/src/
vim user-list.vala +252
```

Remove the line or just add `//` at the beginning of the line. Save and exit.

```
cd ..
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -uc -b
cd ..
sudo dpkg -i unity-greeter_0.1.1-0ubuntu1_*.deb
```

Ubuntu will try to replace the custom built package when performing a system upgrade. Just uncheck unity-greeter to keep the custom one or reinstall the custom one using 'dpkg' after the upgrade.

[Edit]

To prevent the package manager from replacing your custom unity-greeter just run

```
sudo apt-mark hold unity-greeter
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As you were posting, I was working on this, also. I've now posted the result in a PPA, as explained in my answer. Had I not been working on a more complete solution, I would have accepted your answer.

Comment: No problem. A more permanent solution is always welcome. After all not all of us are comfortable working with source code.

Answer (score 2):

At the moment at least this is not currently possible. I have done some reading around before and it seems to be hard coded in. Hopefully the devs will include a way to get rid of them eventually.

Comment: Your answer spurred me to examine the source. The grid is in fact hard coded in the file `src/user-list.vala`. Line 233 is the most interesting. If I get time, perhaps I'll turn the alpha all the way down and make a .deb with the modifictions.

Comment: It is possible in 12.04 via gconf settings.