# How can i remove the white dots in login screen on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10, login-screen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Removing the dots from the lightdm greeter](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72620/removing-the-dots-from-the-lightdm-greeter)

I want to customize the login screen from Ubuntu 11.10 but i cant find the location of the white dots. I know how to change the background image but i can find the location of the white dots.

Greets from tinuz

Comment: You can read this:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/72620/removing-the-dots-from-the-lightdm-greeter

Comment: Thanks for the answer and this answered the question ...