# What is the password for the 'lightdm' user?

Tags: 13.04, lightdm

```
lightdm@hemura-X450CC:/home/hemura$ sudo gsettings set com.canonical.unity-greeter draw-grid false
[sudo] password for lightdm: 
Sorry, try again.
```

i typed the right password but it doesn't work

Comment: I wonder what the "right password" you typed for the lightdm user is...

Answer (score 2):

### It's a system account. It doesn't *have* a password.

Why are you even in a shell as the `lightdm` user? I'd suggest you log out (<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>) and log in as your own user. If that's in the `sudo` group, you'll be able to use your own password to run whatever it is you're trying to run as root.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you want to remove the Unity Greeter dots. Use the following commands, in that order:

```
sudo xhost +SI:localuser:lightdm
sudo su lightdm -s /bin/bash
gsettings set com.canonical.unity-greeter draw-grid false
exit
```

The problem you made was that you prefixed the `gsettings` command with `sudo`, which it doesn't need.

Originally by [jokerdino♦](https://askubuntu.com/users/25798/jokerdino) here: [How do I remove the dots from the lightdm greeter?](https://askubuntu.com/a/121620/176889)