# How do I remove the dots from the lockscreen in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, lock-screen

You can remove the dots from the login screen in 12.04-13.10 [using this method](https://askubuntu.com/a/121620/272023).

How do you remove the dots from the new lock screen in Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove the dots from the login screen?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/72620/how-do-i-remove-the-dots-from-the-login-screen)

Answer (score 24):

Manually went into `dconf-editor` and went to `com.canonical.unity.unity-greeter` and unchecked the option `draw-grid`. For some reason, this worked and not the command line answer from before, which I also tried. Hope this helps.

Comment: It is because the login screen settings are those of user lightdm, but lock screen settings belong to the actual user. A commandline solution would be `gsettings set com.canonical.unity-greeter draw-grid false` (without the preceding two lines)

Comment: Works like a charm. @EdPaton-Williams: If it worked for you, please consider marking it as an accepted answer by clicking the checkmark to the left.

Comment: This worked, but first you must install dconf-editor: `sudo apt-get install dconf-tools`
https://askubuntu.com/questions/22313/what-is-dconf-what-is-its-function-and-how-do-i-use-it

Answer (score 9):

To remove white dots, run the following commands in a Terminal:

```
sudo xhost +SI:localuser:lightdm
sudo su lightdm -s /bin/bash
gsettings set com.canonical.unity-greeter draw-grid false;exit
```

Source: http://www.noobslab.com/2014/04/thingstweaks-to-do-after-install-of.html

Comment: Thanks for that. I don't have my Ubuntu machine in front of me but I'm almost certain that is only for the **login screen**. I tried this method already and the dots are still there for the new **lockscreen**.

Comment: I ran just this line and it worked: gsettings set com.canonical.unity-greeter draw-grid false

I don't know what the other lines are supposed to do.

Comment: Didn't work for lock screen on ubuntu 16.0.2

Answer (score 7):

Just adding this answer (sourced from comments) for easier view. This worked for me on 14.04 LTS for **lock screen**. Thanks to **S Prasanth** for the answer

```
gsettings set com.canonical.unity-greeter draw-grid false
```

To do the same for login screen, one has to become do it as the `lightdm` user. Which can be done by the method described by **@Fat Mind**